# How can I make an android application using Pydroid 3?

Tags: python

Good day, I'm a beginner and I made this program with my android phone using Pydroid 3. I wanted to ask how can I make it into an android application ? Thank you in advance.

```
print("This program calculates the residential electricity bill in leyeco V per day, month and year.")

sum = 0
n = 2
for E in range(0,n):
    P_string = input("Enter the powerr consumption in ilowattsss): ")
    P = float(P_string)
    T_string = input("Enter the hourss of usage per day: ")
    T = float(T_string)
    C = 6.8753
    E = P*T*C
    E1 = E*30
    E2 = E1*12
    print("The appliance has "+str(E)+" electricity cost per day in pesos.")
    print("The appliance has "+str(E1)+" electricity cost per month in pesos.")
    print("The appliance has "+str(E2)+" electricity cost per year in pesos.")
    sum = sum+E

E3 = sum*30
E4 = E3*12
print("The total power consumption cost "+str(sum)+" cost per day in pesos.")
print("The total power consumption cost "+str(E3)+" cost per month in pesos.")
print("The total power consumption cost "+str(E4)+" cost per year in pesos.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean create an app directly from your phone ? If yes, I don't know if it possible.

Even if possible, it is not the easy way. You can use kivy and buildozer packages on a PC instead : https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/